# My equation split over two lines doesn't centre on the page

Tags: equations, subequations, center

I am trying to split an equation over two lines but when I do it doesn't centre in the middle of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{subequation}
\begin{align}
\centering
    \begin{split}
      \textit{SOC}= \alpha + \beta_1\textit{Only languages} + \beta_2\textit{Languages with other subject} \\*+ \beta_3\textit{Social Sciences} + \beta_4\textit{STEM }+ \sum Y + \epsilon
    \end{split}
\tag{2B}
\end{align}
\end{subequation}
```

and this is what comes up:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect?

Comment: @Bernard can it not be centered in the middle of the page? just seems like its aligned to the right hand side of the page at the moment

Comment: The whole block of equations is centred, but the *inner* alignment is to the right  (not the right of the page) because you didn't mark any algnment point

Comment: First of all, remove `\centering` that's out of place there.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Three ways of splitting an equation over 3 lines]

There are many ways to split an equation over two lines and most have different justifications.
The first way shown is what was in the question. There are two problems with this code. First the `\centering` is not needed and second the `align` environment is used but no align marks, `&`, are included so everything is automatically aligned to the right.
Two other ways of splitting up an equation are `multline` (notice only one i, not multiline) and `gather`.
For centering both parts you probably want `gather`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    With \verb|multline|
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{multline}
            \textit{SOC}= \alpha + \beta_1\textit{Only languages} + \beta_2\textit{Languages with other subject} \\*+ \beta_3\textit{Social Sciences} + \beta_4\textit{STEM }+ \sum Y + \epsilon
            \tag{2B}
        \end{multline}
    \end{subequations}
    With \verb|gather|
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{gather*}
            \textit{SOC}= \alpha + \beta_1\textit{Only languages} + \beta_2\textit{Languages with other subject} \\*+ \beta_3\textit{Social Sciences} + \beta_4\textit{STEM }+ \sum Y + \epsilon
            \tag{2B}
        \end{gather*}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `amsmath` environment is `subequations` (with an s on the end) not `subequation`.

Comment: great, thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle makes a good point, that was just copied from the question, I'll make a note of this in the answer.

Comment: @Willoughby I know:-)  but code in questions is supposed to be wrong: code in answers is supposed to be right (because people copy code from answers even if you add a note saying it's wrong)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point again, I'll just remove it as its in the question

Comment: +1 then, thanks for putting up with my complaints:-)